# Process got killed when building docker image on GCP

Tags: docker, google-cloud-platform, pytorch, torchvision, streamlit

I am a newbie of cloud computing and struggling to deploy my web app on google cloud platform for the first time. When I was building docker image, which means I ran the following code

```
docker build -t gcr.io/${PROJECT_ID}/insurance-streamlit:v1 .
```

the process got killed, showing the following error:

```
Killed
The command '/bin/sh -c pip install -r requirements.txt' returned a non-zero code: 137
```

I guessed my app might be too large because the weight file has been more than 100MB. So is there a way to fix it? Please tell me the details, thanks in advance!

PS: my Dockerfile is as below:

```
FROM python:3.7
RUN pip install virtualenv
ENV VIRTUAL_ENV=/venv
RUN virtualenv venv -p python3
ENV PATH="VIRTUAL_ENV/bin:$PATH"

WORKDIR /app
ADD . /app

# Install dependencies
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt

# copying all files over
COPY . /app

# Expose port 
ENV PORT 8501

# cmd to launch app when container is run
CMD streamlit run app.py

# streamlit-specific commands for config
ENV LC_ALL=C.UTF-8
ENV LANG=C.UTF-8
RUN mkdir -p /root/.streamlit
RUN bash -c 'echo -e "\
[general]\n\
email = \"\"\n\
" > /root/.streamlit/credentials.toml'

RUN bash -c 'echo -e "\
[server]\n\
enableCORS = false\n\
" > /root/.streamlit/config.toml
```

And my requirements.txt is like:

```
albumentations==0.4.5
numpy==1.19.0
opencv-python==4.1.0.25
opencv-python-headless==4.2.0.34
pandas==1.0.5
Pillow==7.1.2
streamlit==0.62.0
torch==1.4.0
torchvision==0.5.0
matplotlib
```

Comment: Can you paste your dockerfile content?

Comment: Also, please provide `requirements.txt`.

Comment: Edited, thanks for your comments!

Comment: @MemphisMeng you may have hit out of memory error. Try to to debug with `-it` flag or allocate more memory for container.

Comment: Where is the flag `-it` used?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found that to build your Docker image you should have enough disk space and Python 3.7 installed, also there's a typo at your Docker file - no single quotes `'` at the end of the last string. Beside of that, everything looks good and runs.

Please find my steps below:

1. Enable Google Container Registry API
2. Create VM instance:

```
gcloud compute instances create instance-4 --zone=europe-west3-a --machine-type=e2-medium --image=ubuntu-1804-bionic-v20200701 --image-project=ubuntu-os-cloud --boot-disk-size=50GB
```

3. Follow documentation [Pushing and pulling images](https://cloud.google.com/container-registry/docs/pushing-and-pulling).
4. Install Python 3.7:

```
sudo apt install python3.7
```

5. Build Docker image:

```
docker build -t gcr.io/test-prj/testimage:v1 .
...
Step 16/16 : RUN bash -c 'echo -e "[server]\nenableCORS = false\n" > /root/.streamlit/config.toml
 ---> Running in 57502f97cfbe
/bin/sh: 1: Syntax error: Unterminated quoted string
The command '/bin/sh -c bash -c 'echo -e "[server]\nenableCORS = false\n" > /root/.streamlit/config.toml' returned a non-zero code: 2
```

6. Change last string of the Docker file:

```
" > /root/.streamlit/config.toml'
```

7. Build Docker image again:

```
docker build -t gcr.io/test-prj/testimage:v1 .
...
Step 16/16 : RUN bash -c 'echo -e "[server]\nenableCORS = false\n" > /root/.streamlit/config.toml'
 ---> Running in c1c1f81a2d09
Removing intermediate container c1c1f81a2d09
 ---> 24b6609de554
Successfully built 24b6609de554
Successfully tagged gcr.io/test-prj/testimage:v1
$ docker images
REPOSITORY                            TAG                 IMAGE ID            CREATED             SIZE
gcr.io/test-prj/testimage             v1                  24b6609de554        14 minutes ago      3.87GB
```

8. Push Docker image to the registry:

```
gcloud docker -- push gcr.io/test-prj/testimage:v1
```

9. Create new VM instance and deploy image:

```
gcloud compute instances create-with-container instance-5 --zone=europe-west3-a --machine-type=e2-medium --image=cos-stable-81-12871-148-0 --image-project=cos-cloud --boot-disk-size=50GB --container-image=gcr.io/test-prj/testimage:v1
```

9. Check status of Docker container:

```
instance-5 ~ $ docker ps
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE                                 COMMAND                  CREATED             STATUS                                  PORTS               NAMES
e21b80dc0de7        gcr.io/test-prj/testimage:v1   "/bin/sh -c 'streaml…"   28 seconds ago      Restarting (2) Less than a second ago                       klt-instance-5-caqx
```

and it doesn't look very good.

10. Stop container:

```
instance-5 ~ $docker stop e21b80dc0de7
```

11. Follow the [documentation](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/run/) and run container interactively:

```
instance-5 ~ $docker run --name test -it gcr.io/test-prj/testimage:v1
Usage: streamlit run [OPTIONS] TARGET [ARGS]...

Error: Invalid value: File does not exist: app.py
```

no surprise because I don't have `app.py`.

After that, I've added some dummy `app.py`, rebuild and finally it works:

```
instance-6 ~ $ docker ps
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE                                 COMMAND                  CREATED             STATUS              PORTS               NAMES
1de2e8ded5d8        gcr.io/test-prj/testimage:v2   "/bin/sh -c 'streaml…"   7 minutes ago       Up 7 minutes                           klt-instance-6-yezv
```

Comment: Thanks, Serhii. I think your way should be the right way but I still met this error. So I wonder what pakcges you put in the `requirements.txt`? I need Pytorch and it got killed every time it is installing PyTorch at step 8/16. I know Torch is a huge package so I'm not usre if you check it.

Comment: I didn't change `requirements.txt` at all. I changed Docker file (`'` was added at step 6) and used some dummy `app.py` with `print` command. Also, I've installed Python 3.7 to GCP VM which I used to build Docker image. At which step do you have an error?

Comment: I still got killed when collecting torch, which is step 8/16

Comment: Could you please check if you have enough disk space and Python 3.7 installed in your system? Please update your question with build log.

Comment: I think yes because I used the terminal on browser and created the VM as you suggested.

Comment: In my case, I have to install Python 3.7 manually to Ubuntu 18.04 LTS based VM instance.